# Can i store multiple add-on for a product in column of table as JSON?

Tags: mysql, database-design, relational-database, database-schema, entity-attribute-value

Prob: I have a table which contains list of toys(dolls).while purchasing user can choose options(black dress or white dress) and accessories(earring and anklet).

options 1: First i thought of adding 2 different table for options and accessories.
   [http://imgur.com/a/FnE6O](https://imgur.com/a/FnE6O)[image: Database schema]

But as i am never going to filter/search on these table so i thought of putting these options as JSON in seperate column.So that frontend can easily render JSON as options to user
[image]

**QUES**: As i have to add total price from options and accessories
Is this ok to store these type of details as JSON format?
I am also open for other suggestions which is easily maintainable

Comment: Yes, but only for random options, _not_ for structure that you give an example of.  See my [_EAV blog_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/eav).

Comment: Your question is very similar to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31972056/mysql-embedded-json-vs-table/31977656#31977656

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using an sql-database (and it looks like you are) I really advise you against keeping the data as `JSON` inside.

Even though [MySQL 5.7.8](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html) gives you a good way to access data inside json types, you never know when you are going to need to filter/search/group based in that data.

A quick example that jumps here is that you want to give a user that buys a new doll (productid == 1) a list of all the add-on that people that also bought that doll (productid == 1) purchased in the last week (or month). If you are going to save that data as `JSON` it will be very hard to query.

I know that your example shows only the meta-data of the add-ons and options, but it's "easy" to go and also save the actual purchases that way (just as add-on to the purchase-row itself).

I advise against it.